# Reading a managed app config in Flutter Android

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

How can an EMM/MDM controlled device's flutter built app read the mananged application config profile information?

Background.  The application currently is reading environment variables that are getting pushed in via the build process and I am looking to change this to using an MDM application profile that we can control.

Today:

`const environment = String.fromEnvironment('environment', defaultValue: 'dev');`

Where I want to go is implement [this](https://developer.android.com/work/managed-configurations) in flutter but I can't determine how to get access to:RestrictionsManager:

```
var myRestrictionsMgr =
        activity?.getSystemService(Context.RESTRICTIONS_SERVICE) as RestrictionsManager
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure this out.  In the `MainActivity.kt`:

```
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "com.yourstuff.whatever/something"

   override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
    MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler {
      call, result ->
      var myRestrictionsMgr =
        activity?.getSystemService(Context.RESTRICTIONS_SERVICE) as RestrictionsManager
        var appRestrictions: Bundle = myRestrictionsMgr.applicationRestrictions
    
       result.success(appRestrictions.getString(call.method))
    }
  }
}
```

And in flutter to call it:

```
const platform = const MethodChannel("com.yourstuff.whatever/something"); 
platform.invokeMethod("restrictionname");
```

Comment: Did you managed also for Ios ?

Comment: It was over 3 years ago so I don't recall!